# product of independent random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X \sim U(-10,10)$ and $Y$ have a pdf $f_Y(y) = \dfrac{1}{t} y ^ {(1/t) -1} $, $0\leq y\leq 1$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are both independent, what is the pdf of $XY$?

---

Here is my attempt:

Let $W=XY$, so that $f_W(w) = \displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{|y|} f_X\left(\dfrac{w}{y}\right)f_Y(y)dy$.

$$ f_W(w) = \displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{y} \left ( \dfrac{1}{20} \right )\dfrac{1}{t} y^{(1/t)-1}dy$$

I am not sure of the bounds. I chose from $y=\dfrac{w}{10}$ to $y=1$. It looks incomplete.

Any insights?

Thanks

Comment: You have $f_X =1_{(-10,10)}$, and $f_Y(t) = {1 \over t} y^{{1 \over t}-1} 1_{[0,1]}(t)$, substituting these in should give appropriate integration bounds.

Comment: $X$ is uniformly distributed over $[-10,10]$. So, $-10 \leq \frac{w}{y} \leq 10$. This means for $y>0$, $y \leq \frac{w}{10}$ and since $y\leq 1$, then the bounds above are chosen. But I plotted them and result is not what I expected. Where could be the error?

Comment: $\int_{|w| \over 10}^1 \cdots$. Note the absolute value...